# AutoScroll on chat exchange doesn't work in chrome 61

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, google-chrome

I updated the chrome to version 61, and the auto-scroll stopped working, it is necessary to scroll down the page manually. The problem does not occur in the previous version or in firefox.

Also, the reply icon no longer working when the message replied to is not in the current chat page. (Middle click still works and opens the link in new tab.)

Comment: SE developers, please refer to this if and when fixing this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061901/chrome-61-body-doesnt-scroll

Comment: This seems to have broken for me again :|

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was already in the process of upgrading chat jQuery (and some related jQuery plugins) when Chrome 61 hit, and which happens to also fix the issue.

This has been tested and is now deployed.

Comment: Awesome! What about answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061901/chrome-61-body-doesnt-scroll) too? :)

Comment: Thanks for support! :D

Comment: Thanks, it was so annoying to scroll chat myself for every single new message. :D